# How to tell py.test to install required modules?

Tags: python, pytest

I am using py.test to run the tests but it may fail to run because it fails to collect the tests due to missing dependency modules.

I have to mention that my setup.py already contains these modules:

```
setup(
    ...
    tests_require=['soappy'],
    ...
```

Still, it seems that I'm missing something, something that will tell `py.test` to install these modules.

Answer (score 0):

pytest does not deal with setup.py itself, the test_requires is something that setuptools cares for by way of invoking setup.py.  The docs show two ways how to integrate a pytest run with setup.py: http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#integrating-with-distutils-python-setup-py-test